# I want to convert JSON to XML which has inner objects

Tags: javascript, json, xml

This is my JSON
I want to convert the JSON to XML .
I tried this code but my output is different from expected output.

```
{
  "elements": [
    {
      "type": "dropdown",
      "innerelements": {
        "c1": [],
        "c2": [],
        "c3": [],
        "c4": []
      },
      "id": 106592,
      "page": 1,
      "position": 15,
      "title": "Grade Level",
      "description": "",
      "class": "",
      "required": false,
      "value": "",
      "responseElementID": 0,
      "responseDetailID": 0,
      "response": "",
      "elementpermission": "",
      "placeholder": "",
      "autocomplete": {
        "type": "",
        "special": "",
        "restrict": true
      },
      "multiresponse": false,
      "validation": {
        "config": {},
        "functional": []
      },
      "field": {
        "name": "U_FB_STUDENTS_SIBLINGS.GRADE_LEVEL",
        "validation": {},
        "value": ""
      },
      "layout": "large",
      "workflow": {
        "enabled": false,
        "link": false,
        "element": 0,
        "value": "",
        "hidden": ""
      },
      "otherchoice": false,
      "container": {
        "enabled": true,
        "id": 106586,
        "column": 3,
        "position": 1
      },
      "collection": {
        "table": {
          "extension": "",
          "name": "",
          "filterby": "",
          "columns": []
        },
        "data": {
          "childrow": [
            {
              "id": 1,
              "columns": {},
              "status": {
                "delete": false,
                "insert": false
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

````
My Output is:
```
<elements><type>dropdown</type><innerelements></innerelements><id>106592</id><page>1</page><position>15</position><title>Grade Level</title><description></description><class></class><required>false</required><value></value><responseElementID>0</responseElementID><responseDetailID>0</responseDetailID><response></response><elementpermission></elementpermission><placeholder></placeholder><autocomplete><type></type><special></special><restrict>true</restrict></autocomplete><multiresponse>false</multiresponse><validation><config></config></validation><field><name>U_FB_STUDENTS_SIBLINGS.GRADE_LEVEL</name><validation></validation><value></value></field><layout>large</layout><workflow><enabled>false</enabled><link>false</link><element>0</element><value></value><hidden></hidden></workflow><otherchoice>false</otherchoice><container><enabled>true</enabled><id>106586</id><column>3</column><position>1</position></container><collection><table><extension></extension><name></name><filterby></filterby></table><data><childrow><id>1</id><columns></columns><status><delete>false</delete><insert>false</insert></status></childrow></data></collection></elements>
```

Expected output is:
```
<elements><type>dropdown</type><innerelements><c1/><c2/><c3/><c4/></innerelements><id>106592</id><page>1</page><position>15</position><title>Grade Level</title><description></description><class></class><required>false</required><value></value><responseElementID>0</responseElementID><responseDetailID>0</responseDetailID><response></response><elementpermission></elementpermission><placeholder></placeholder><autocomplete><type></type><special></special><restrict>true</restrict></autocomplete><multiresponse>false</multiresponse><validation><config></config></validation><field><name>U_FB_STUDENTS_SIBLINGS.GRADE_LEVEL</name><validation></validation><value></value></field><layout>large</layout><workflow><enabled>false</enabled><link>false</link><element>0</element><value></value><hidden></hidden></workflow><otherchoice>false</otherchoice><container><enabled>true</enabled><id>106586</id><column>3</column><position>1</position></container><collection><table><extension></extension><name></name><filterby></filterby></table><data><childrow><id>1</id><columns></columns><status><delete>false</delete><insert>false</insert></status></childrow></data></collection></elements>


```
can anyone help me in this
````

Comment: Which code have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

How have you converted these files? I've used [this site](https://www.freeformatter.com/json-to-xml-converter.html) and the inner elements are preserved, although the generated XML is a bit more verbose. Hope it helps.